# how to get present date and next dates fromm stored db

Tags: php, sql

i have a database containing show dates having today's previous and next days i want to filter those dates which containing only today's and next upcoming dates but not previous date . how can do that

I have written sql has

```
SELECT Distinct(date) FROM `shows` WHERE movid='$id' ORDER BY date
```

Comment: The answers below are ok but you have to keep in mind that if your app is hosted on a server whose's time is different from your own, some small issues might occur

Comment: if we are using it on locally it'll work as it on server we have specify servers date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Distinct(date) FROM `shows` WHERE movid='$id' AND date >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Distinct(date) FROM `shows` WHERE date  >= CURRENT_DATE()
```